# How to find the data source of a Pivot Table using OpenXML

Tags: c#, openxml, epplus

I am using EPP to open and edit an existing excel document.

The document contains 2 sheets - one with a pivot table (named Pivot) and one with the data `(Data!$A$1:$L$9899)`.

I have a reference to the ExcelPivotTable with the code below, but can't find any properties that relate to the data source.

```
ExcelPackage package = new ExcelPackage(pivotSpreadsheet);

        foreach (ExcelWorksheet worksheet in package.Workbook.Worksheets)
        {
            if (worksheet.PivotTables.Count > 0)
            {
                pivotWorkSheetName = worksheet.Name;
                pivotTable = worksheet.PivotTables[0];
            }
        }
```

How do I get the name and range of the source data? Is there an obvious property that I'm missing or do I have to go hunting through some xml?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PivotTables use a data cache for the data store for performance & abstraction reasons.  Remember, you can have a pivot that points to a web service call. The cache itself is what stores that reference.  For pivots that refer to data elsewhere in a workbook, you can access it in EPPlus like this:

```
worksheet.PivotTables[0].CacheDefinition.SourceRange.FullAddress;
```

Comment: Any idea how to UPDATE this value (I'm updating the datasource and need to update the reference in the PivotTable)?

Answer (score 2):

If anyone is interested to update the data source with OpenXML SDK 2.5 then here is the code I used.

```
    using (var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetDocument.Open(filepath, true))
    {
            PivotTableCacheDefinitionPart ptp = spreadsheet.WorkbookPart.PivotTableCacheDefinitionParts.First();
            ptp.PivotCacheDefinition.RefreshOnLoad = true;//refresh the pivot table on document load
            ptp.PivotCacheDefinition.RecordCount = Convert.ToUInt32(ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count);
            ptp.PivotCacheDefinition.CacheSource.WorksheetSource.Reference = "A1:" + IntToLetters(ds.Tables[0].Columns.Count) + (ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count + 1);//Cell Range as data source
            ptp.PivotTableCacheRecordsPart.PivotCacheRecords.RemoveAllChildren();//it is rebuilt when pivot table is refreshed
            ptp.PivotTableCacheRecordsPart.PivotCacheRecords.Count = 0;//it is rebuilt when pivot table is refreshed
    }
    public string IntToLetters(int value)//copied from another stackoverflow post
    {
            string result = string.Empty;
            while (--value >= 0)
            {
                result = (char)('A' + value % 26) + result;
                value /= 26;
            }
            return result;
    }
```